# F# application hanging when running via Mono

Tags: .net, f#, mono

I'm trying to target a Linux box while developing an F# application on Windows.

Right now I have a working version of one of my experiments which runs fine on MS .NET framework on Windows (VS and Xamarin), but when I try to run it via Mono (either on Windows or Linux via `mono output.exe`) it doesn't work as expected.

The application starts normally but when it calls an external module which uses `async` methods and `await` ([Link to the relevant class](http://soundcloud.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Source/ApiLibrary/SoundCloudClient.cs)), it seems to hang the execution indefinitely (no error is printed to the console).

Is this a Mono limitation? Is there any way to validate if some code/library is incompatible with Mono?

Mono Linux version:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

Mono Windows version:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.3.0 (master/6cd4ddc)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           normal
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notification:  Thread + polling
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)

Comment: Perhaps this has nothing to do with mono itself, but with process you call from the program...

Comment: I'm only calling the library shown in the question like this:
let user = soundcloud.Users.[userId].Get()
This can indeed have nothing to do with Mono, but as it works on Windows and it doesn't on Linux via Mono, it is probably the most likely cause. But considering what you say, the code that I've linked above should be supported on the Mono version I've specified, right?

Comment: Also, I've just tried now and it doesn't work on Windows when I run the program via mono either. So it really seems like it is Mono related (independently if it is Linux or Windows). I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a small, self-contained testcase? If yes, file a bug report against the runtime on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: While trying to reproduce that test case (copying the above 3rd party code to a new project) I was blocked by what seems a Mono limitation. I've created a new thread on their mailing list, but I still haven't got an answer: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Does-Mono-support-System-Net-Http-HttpContentExtensions-tp4663373.html

Comment: Also I started this question because after talking with Xamarin support they informed me Mono Linux is not supported by them (first I thought this was a Mono Linux problem only), and pointed me to Mono community. Mono tag in Stackoveflow is referred by Mono as an official support community ( http://www.mono-project.com/Community ).